# Extract coefficient from LinearModelFit

Tags: fitting

I want to know how to extract the coefficients from the result of `LinearModelFit`.

The functions used to fit are complicated and being in different forms. For example `Sin[kx]Sin[ky]` and `Cos[kx]-Cos[ky]`. The final result is

```
9.06697*10^-18 + 2.06844*10^-17 (Cos[kx] - Cos[ky]) + 
2.04521*10^-17 (Cos[kx] - Cos[ky]) Cos[kz] + 
0.0123472 (Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + Cos[kz]) + 
2.39738*10^-17 (-Cos[kx] - Cos[ky] + 2 Cos[kz]) + 
1.30737*10^-17 (Cos[kx] Cos[ky] + Cos[kx] Cos[kz] + 
Cos[ky] Cos[kz]) + 
1.94961*10^-17 (2 Cos[kx] Cos[ky] - (Cos[kx] + Cos[ky]) Cos[kz]) - 
4.46158*10^-17 Sin[kx] - 
1.65859*10^-16 (Cos[ky] - Cos[kz]) Sin[kx] + 
4.86171*10^-16 (Cos[ky] + Cos[kz]) Sin[kx] - 0.0491758 Sin[ky] - 
2.85105*10^-19 (-Cos[kx] + Cos[kz]) Sin[ky] - 
0.0228324 (Cos[kx] + Cos[kz]) Sin[ky] + 
5.85464*10^-17 Sin[kx] Sin[ky] - 2.54947*10^-17 Sin[kz] - 
4.93221*10^-17 (Cos[kx] - Cos[ky]) Sin[kz] - 
1.66687*10^-16 (Cos[kx] + Cos[ky]) Sin[kz] + 
4.10949*10^-18 Sin[kx] Sin[kz] - 2.00305*10^-16 Sin[ky] Sin[kz]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `"BestFitParameters"` property.